# While loop not ending when condition is met

Tags: c++, while-loop

```
void getPlayerRolls(int RollValues[], int& AttemptCount) {
    int i = 0;
    int FrameNumber = 0;
    int RollNumber = 0;

    while(RollValues[i] != -1) {
        FrameNumber++;

        cout << "Frame # " << FrameNumber << endl;
        cout << "Roll #1 "
             << " ";
        cin >> RollValues[i];
        i++;

        cout << "Roll #2 "
             << " ";
        cin >> RollValues[i];
        i++;

        cout << endl;

    }
}
```

My expectation is that when a -1 is entered for one of the roll values that the program terminates. I tried to create a while loop that works with an array but I am having trouble determining how to do this.

Comment: `RollValues[i] ` could represent a bug. How big is this array?

Comment: After first iteration, `i` will be equal to `2`, but nothing was read into `RollValues[2]`. You only read two values per loop and increment `i` 3 times.

Comment: `RollValues[i]` is being tested before inserting values into `RollValues[i]`. You want to test after. Probably after every insert, not every two inserts..

Comment: We can't see anything suggesting that the program should terminate. The function should return if the rest of the logic is sound though.

Comment: Don't you see that you increase `i` twice after the user input? When you check `RollValues[i] != -1` you are no longer pointing to the element you set to -1. This is a very weird program. You should start with good C++ book. Use vectors and so.

Comment: My expectation is to continue taking in role values until "-1" is entered by the user. "-1" is like a hotkey I am trying to create that will end the program.

Comment: I attempted to look at 'RollValues[i]'  for that -1 value but realized im only looking at the index value.

Comment: Removed the extra i++ at the end. Didn't proof read my code before submitting. This was not part of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I removed lines from your function that are not part of the problem, but maybe this will clarify:

```
while(RollValues[i] != -1) {
    cin >> RollValues[i];
    i++;
    cin >> RollValues[i];
    i++;
    i++;
}
```

What is the value of `i` by the time the loop condition variable is tested?

The first rollvalue entered is read into some place in the array, but then `i` is incremented, so if you read back from RollValues[i] you read from *a different place in memory*!  Not only that, you never look at the first roll before accepting the second.  And then you increment `i` yet again.  By the time you're back at the top of the loop, `i` has been advanced 3 times, and neither of the entered rolls is ever tested.

You have other issues too, such as

- receiving an array has no "size" information associated, so you do not now how big of an array the caller provided.  Your code therefore cannot protect against overruning the memory.
- in your while loop, you advance 3 times per iteration, so even if your loop condition checks for boundary cases, you still could have walked off the end of the array *before* getting back to the top of the loop.

Therefore, I suggest the following:

1) pass in the size of your array into your function, or use a safer data structure, such as std::array or std::vector

2) only process a single roll per loop, and check that you're within bounds before advancing.

3) don't advance your index variable until you're done looking at the value in that place that it refers.

Comment: This did not solve my problem. I must use the function exactly as they are and cannot use vectors. Arrays only.

Comment: @DarkLordSauron  If you "must use the function exactly as they are" then it is what you pass into the function that makes the difference.  Make sure RollValues is initialized to all -1 in every spot except the last two so that the loop will continue until it gets to the end.  And why does the function pass in AttemptCount and then never use it?

Comment: Given this interface, it is not possible for you to write a correct function that stays in bounds.  Sorry, if that's assigned that way, you're being taught unsafe practice. 
If the array is populated with -1's, then when you get to your loop it'll stop before it starts because the condition is already false.